How can I include my google cloud storage private key in my Nextjs app hosted on Vercel?
I'm trying to use Google Cloud Storage to upload image files in my Nextjs website. Everything works fine in development, but as soon as I deploy to Vercel, it's saying that there is no private key. I have it stored as an environment variable for my Vercel project, it looks something like this:
GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----blablablablabla\nblablablabla\nblablablablaetc-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"

I tried using a solution I found that converts it to json and then parses it like this:
GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY={"privateKey":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----blablablablabla\nblablablabla\nblablablablaetc-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"}

but that didn't work either.
I tried replacing the \n in my server function:
credentials: {
        client_email: process.env.GCLOUD_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        private_key: process.env.GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
      },

But that didn't work either.
Has anyone done this before? Is there something I'm missing that I need to do to use my private key from GCS on Vercel?

Just to confirm, are you using this is a client or server component?

It's in my _actions.js, so its a 'use server' component.

Set up the environment variable inside the Vercel UI, not just in a .env file if that's what you've done.
See https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables


It is set in my Vercel environment variables. I've read that vercel can handle \n without problem, so I've tried accessing it as process.env.GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY and as process.env.GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\n/g, "\n"), but neither seem to be able to use the private key.
